# Strange location on my network

Tags: windows-7, networking

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this. But I noticed sometimes on my network strange location. Here are the pictures. I am using Windows 7 Professional.

Under **Network**:

[image]

And **after doubleclick**:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just another computer in your network.

In other words, wifi? If you've a router at home, which has multiple devices connected to it, they will list under your network.

You tried to access it, and it asked you to enter credidentials.

---

This is off topic, but very important:

**Always** set a proper password for wireless connections, or anyone can connect.

Because anyone can connect, anyone can also hijack your traffic. This includes passwords sent in plain text, website sessions (facebook etc.) or even access your online banking service, if you use it and the session is active.

MITM (**Man-In-The-Middle)** attacks are extremely easy to perform, for example, you can do all the things listed above with a single application on a rooted android device.

Comment: I have my wi fi network, and I am alone on it. nearest neighbour is about 200m with forest in between us...

Comment: Well, do you have a phone connected to it? Does your router act as a modem at the same time, or do you have an external modem? @skywalker

Comment: yes you are right, I looked at dhcp on router, and there is connected device... Really strange.

Comment: Maybe there's someone using your wifi? :)

Comment: Yes there is someone using it, I didn't put any password because I thought everybody is at safe distance, but it seems they are not. Thanks Christian.

Comment: **Always** put a password. Do you know anything about man-in-the-middle attacks? @skywalker

Comment: @skywalker It is extremely common for wifi to leak outside the house. With the help of a small satellite dish and some careful pointing, it is fairly easy to connect to wifi networks over 1km away.

Comment: @David You don't even need that, just a powerfull antenna.